# Live Chat SDK - How to disable minimize chat button for Android?

Tags: liveagent, snap-ins

[image]

For iOS, I was setup SCSChatConfiguration for disabme minimize button. [allowMinimization]

(http://forcedotcom.github.io/ServiceSDK-iOS/releases/api/224.0/Classes/SCSChatConfiguration.html)

Android SDK didn't have an variable for disable it.

(http://forcedotcom.github.io/ServiceSDK-Android/releases/chat/4.1.1/api/reference/com/salesforce/android/chat/ui/ChatUIConfiguration.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by calling `defaultToMinimized(false)`

```
ChatUIConfiguration uiConfig = new ChatUIConfiguration.Builder()
  .chatConfiguration(chatConfiguration)
  .queueStyle(QueueStyle.EstimatedWaitTime) // Use estimated wait time
  .defaultToMinimized(false)                // Start in full-screen mode
  .build();
```

Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.service_sdk_android.meta/service_sdk_android/android_chat_basic_setup.htm